# monte carlo for a selection problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, stochastic-programming, simulation, stochastic-process

What type of Monte Carlo simulation is suitable for solving this problem? Also, how can we select results after simulation to guarantee feasibility?[image]